# Cannot DROP the index because it is not a statistics collection

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, drop

I'm trying to execute this command on Sql Server Management Studio:

```
DROP STATISTICS dbo.TableName.StatsName
```

But I'm receiving this error:

> Cannot DROP the index because it is not a statistics collection.

Also, if I try to go on the table "Statistics" folder on the navigation menu, and try to drop with contextual menu, the voice *drop* is disabled.

When I try to look for it in the `sys.stats` table, I have the following result:

```
Auto_Created: 0
User_Created: 0
```

### Is there a way to drop this kind of statistic?

EDIT

Thanks to CR241 answer and Dan Guzman comment I was able to find out some solution to this problem. I wanted to ALTER an nvarchar column length, but couldn't do that because there were some constraints on it.
I had the same problem on a lot of database tables. It was because there were many indexes and statistics created with Database Tuning Advisor. 
So I created a script to delete them all (ideal would be to delete and restore, after altering all columns).
Maybe this will be useful to someone else:

```
 GO
DECLARE selectIndexes CURSOR FOR
SELECT  
     QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(i.name) as FullIndexName
    FROM sys.indexes  i
    INNER JOIN sys.tables  t ON i.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.stats  s ON s.object_id = i.object_id and s.name = i.name
    LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc ON i.Name = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
            AND OBJECT_NAME(i.Object_ID) = tc.TABLE_NAME
    where QUOTENAME(i.name) like '__dta_%' and i.type_desc = 'NONCLUSTERED';



    DECLARE @fullIndexName nvarchar(max);

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = '';

    OPEN selectIndexes
FETCH NEXT FROM selectIndexes INTO @fullIndexName
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    set @sql = @sql+ 'DROP INDEX ' + @fullIndexName + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

    FETCH NEXT FROM selectIndexes INTO @fullIndexName
END

CLOSE selectIndexes
DEALLOCATE selectIndexes

print @sql;
--exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Give the message speccifies "cannot drop the *index*", it seems it may be an index instead of a statistics object. Note that indexes also have statistics so indexes appear under both Indexes and Statistics nodes in SSMS Object Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should drop the index, then it's stats also get dropped automatically which was created with the same name as index. So I don't think you need to drop stats manually.

SQL Server keeps track of user created statistics through in [sys.stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) i.e. user_created. That’s why while creating a new index, to avoid this error, we must add following IF EXISTS() code, before actual index creation code.

Here is an Example:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE name = N'IX_TestTable_1'
AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestTable]') )

DROP INDEX [dbo].[TestTable].[IX_TestTable_1]
GO

IF EXISTS ( SELECT *
FROM sys.stats
WHERE name = N'IX_TestTable_1'
AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestTable]')
AND user_created = 1 )

DROP STATISTICS [dbo].[TestTable].[IX_TestTable_1]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TestTable_1 ON TestTable(Col1)
```

Must keep in mind that, only user created stats can be dropped. So if we just check existence of stats through name, it will return TRUE, but when it will try to drop that statistics, it will give following error.

```
Cannot DROP the index ‘[dbo].[TestTable].[IX_TestTable_1]’ because it is not a statistics collection.
```

Please check this for knowing about [sys.stats (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> auto_created: Indicates whether the statistics were automatically
>   created by SQL Server.
>
> 0 = Statistics were not automatically created by SQL Server.
>
> 1 = Statistics were automatically created by SQL Server.